# Exporting Postgres table to formatted document

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to export a PSQL table into a nicely formatted document (something that looks like a manual)? For example, if I had "Chapter", "Description" and "Date Modified" in a table, how could I turn that into an automated document? Perhaps with LaTex?

Comment: I'd do this with a Python script or similar that queries the DB and emits markup in your desired format - TeX, asciidoc, HTML, PDF, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a nice-ish report using pgAdmin III

Open the Query Window

Run your query

Main Menu > File > Quick Report

This can make an HTML document with your query output

Another option would be the [`query_to_xml`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING) function, then use XSLT to transform it as you wish.